# If $\langle X,<\rangle$ is a total order which is c.c.c. in the order topology then it has a dense subset of cardinality $\leq\omega_1$

Tags: set-theory

I have been trying to solve a few questions in Kunen's book (Set Theory An Introduction To Independence Proofs) and I got stuck with the following question :

> Let $\langle X,<\rangle$ be a total ordering which is $c.c.c$ in the order topology.
>
> Show that $X$ has a dense subset of cardinality $\le \omega_1$

I would really appreciate any help with this question

Thanks

Comment: Note the asterisk, indicating more than average work or difficulty.

Comment: Actually I have no relevant idea or direction to share, I did try few things (based on the Suslin line section) but all of my work was useless .. I just need some help .. I will edit my post if I will get some progress.

Answer (score 1):

For any topological space $X$ the cellularity $c(X)$ is the least infinite cardinal $k$ such that any open cellular (discrete) family in $X$ has cardinal $k$ or less. (An open cellular family is a family of pair-wise disjoint open sets). And the density $d(X)$ is the least infinite cardinal $k'$ such that $X$ has a dense subset of cardinal $k'$ or less. (It has been said in jest that "There are no finite cardinals in point-set topology".).

It is an  easy exercise that $c(X)\le d(X).$

Let $(X,<,T)$ be a linear space. That is, $<$ is a linear (total) order on $X,$ and $T$ is the topology induced by $<.$

We prove that $d(X)\le c(X)^+,$ (...$k^+$ is the least infinite cardinal greater than the infinite cardinal $k$...), and conclude that $d(X)=c(X)$ or $d(X)=c(X)^+.$ So if $(X,<,T)$ is a Suslin line then $\omega=c(X)<d(X)\le c(X)^+=\omega_1,$ so $d(X)=\omega_1.$

Lemma. For $\emptyset\ne V\in T$ there is a unique open cellular family $V^*\subset T$ such that (i) $\cup V^*=V,$  and (ii) each $ U\in V^*$ is a non-empty $<$-convex open set. Proof: For $x,y \in V$ let $x\sim y$ iff the open interval between $x$ and  $y$ is a subset of $V.$ Let $V^*$ be the set of $\sim$-equivalence classes. I will leave it to the reader to confirm that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $V,$ and that the $\sim$-equivalence classes are open and $<$-convex, and that $V^*$ is unique.

By def'n of $c(X),$ if $\emptyset\ne V\in T$ then $|V^*|\le c(X). $

Now let $c(X)=k$ and assume $d(X)>k$ (because if $d(X)=c(X)$ then we're done).

We show that $d(X)=k^+.$ We construct a collection $F=\{F_a:a\in k^+\}$ of open cellular families in $X ,$ none of them containing $\emptyset,$ and construct a Choice Function  $D:\cup F\to X$ such that $\{D(f):f\in \cup F\}$ is dense in $X.$

Step 1. Pesky isolated points. Let $X^i=\{x\in X: \{x\} \in T\}.$ Since $(X^i)^*=\{\{x\}:x\in X^i\}$ we have $|X^i|=|(X^i)^*|\le c(X)<d(X).$ Let $F_0=(X^i)^*$ and let $D(\{x\})=x$ for $x\in X^i.$

Step 2. Since $(X^i)^*$ is an open cellular family we have $|X^i|=|(X^i)^*|\le c(X)<d(X)$ so $X\ne \overline {X^i}.$

Let $F_1=(X\setminus \overline {X^i})^*.$

Step 3. Inductive construct (i). For $0\ne a\in k^+:$ Assume $F_a$ is a non-empty family of pair-wise disjoint non-empty open convex sets. That is, $\emptyset \ne F_a=(\cup F_a)^*. $ And that each $f\in F_a$ is disjoint from $X^i.$  For $f\in F_a$ let $D(f)\in f\setminus \{\min f, \max f\}$ regardless of whether $\min f$ or $\max f$ exist. Now for brevity let $f^-=\{x\in f:x<D(f)\}$ and $f^+=\{x\in f: x>D(f)\}$.

And define $F_{a+1}=\cup \{\{f^-,f^+\}: f\in F_a\}.$

Step 4. Inductive construct (ii). For $0\ne a=\cup a \in k^+:$ Let $f\in F_a$ iff $f$ is the non-empty interior of $\cap \{H(b):0\ne b\in a\}$ for some $H:a\setminus \{0\}\to \cup_{0\ne b\in a}F_b$ such that (1) $H(b)\in F_b$ and (2) if $0\ne b\in c \in a$ then $H(b)\supset H(c).$

At this point I will leave it to you to see if you can finish.

You must show that $F_a$ is not empty in Step 4, using the fact rhat $\{D(g):g \in \cup_{b\in a}F_b\} $ is not dense in $X$ because its cardinal is at most $c(X)$, and $c(X)<d(X)$.

Then to see that Step 4 cannot apply when $a=k^+$: Suppose instead that dom $(H)=k^+\setminus \{0\}.$ With $H(b)^-$ and $H(b)^+$ defined as $f^-$ and $f^+$ are defined in (3), let $\phi(b)=H(b)^+$ if $H(b+1)=H(b)^-$ and let $\phi(b)=H(b)^-$ if $H(b+1)=H(b)^+.$ Then $\{\phi (b):0\ne b\in k^+\}$ is an open cellular family of cardinal $k^+>c(X),$ which is absurd. We use this now  to show that no non-empty convex open set can be disjoint from the image of the Choice Function $D$.

Remarks. In Step 3, when $0\ne a\in k^+$ and $f\in F_a$ then the only members of $F_{a+1}$ that are $not$ disjoint from $f$ are $f^-$ and $f^+$.......For $f,g \in \cup F=\cup_{a\in k^+}F_a$ let $f<_W g \iff f\supsetneqq g. $ Then $(\cup F, <_W)$ is a set-theoretic $k^+$-Suslin tree.

Comment: Arthur Jensen showed that if $V=L$ then there exists an $\omega_1$-Suslin tree and hence a Suslin line. By methods of iterated forcing, it is consistent with ZFC that there is no Suslin tree and hence no Suslin line.

Comment: Jensen's first name is Ronald.

Comment: @AndreasBlass .Right. There's an Arthur J. somewhere in my memory too but I dk where.